# JAXRS - Query Params are empty strings

Tags: jax-rs

I am trying to create a simple rest service that reads the query params in a url.

```
public Response getBalanceSnapshot(
    @DefaultValue("abc") @QueryParam("typeofid") String t,
    @DefaultValue("def") @QueryParam("id") String i) {

    //    public Response getBalanceSnapshot(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    //    String t = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("parameter1");
    //    String i = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("parameter1");

    if (i == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(
                Response.status(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
                        .entity("name parameter is mandatory")
                        .build());
    }

    if (t.length() == 0) {
        return Response.status(200).entity("empty string").build();
    }

    return Response.status(200)
            .entity("query params are " + t + " and " + i)
           .build();
}
```

If request is - 
http://localhost:8080/sampleresource/firstendpoint?typeofid=acc_id&id=1234

Then expected response is `query params are acc_id and 1234`. 
Actual response is . `query params are`

The strings are not null. But both lengths are `0`.

I have also tried using the URI info to get the params. But that gives a different error.

Comment: `t` and `i` will never be `null` anyway cuz you put `@DefaultValue`.

Comment: but why are the default values are not printed?

Answer (score 0):

Let's test some other features of Java.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String s = null;
        System.out.println("aaa" + s + "bbb");
    }
}
```

The program prints

```
aaanullbbb
```

not

```
aaabbb
```

When you see

```
query params are  and
```

not

```
query params are acc_id and 1234
```

That means the `t` ant the `i` is actually `""`, not `null`.

Are you sure you're requesting to the right method?

Comment: thanks for the insight. As of now, I have implemented only one method. And I am doing a get call to the correct url.